# how to loop two loops one in another

Tags: r

I have a list (lst1) which contain 10 data.frame. Each data.frame has a variable `ID`. I also have a IDlist. Is it a way that we can create a looping codes so I can generate an excel book which contain those 10 data, one in each sheet, with one match ID in IDlist?

The tricky part is we need to looping through the IDlist list as well as passing through the lst1. Any advice?

I have some codes that I wrote but it won't work. Hopefully it can give you some idea on what I want to do.

```
for (i in IDlist) {
  
  # create a workbook
  tempwb <- createWorkbook()
  
  for(j in seq_along(lst1)){

    # store the ID -specific subset of the dataset
     data.subset <-lst1[[j]] %>% filter(ID == i)

    # add worksheet
    addWorksheet(tempwb, sheetName = lst1[[j]])} # I want the sheetname= dataname, what should I do? mine should be wrong

## How can I load subset to each sheet?

    file.name <- paste0(i,".xlsx")

    ### save workbook
    saveWorkbook(tempwb, paste0(output_dir,file.name), overwrite = TRUE)
  }
```

Comment: Share code if u can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(writexl)

lst1 <- list(data1 = mpg, data2 = mpg, data3 = mpg, `data4/\\bad name` = mpg)

# Remove any illegal characters from names:
names(lst1) <- names(lst1) %>% 
    stringr::str_replace_all("[:punct:]", " ")

IDlist <- mpg %>% pull(cyl) %>% unique

make_one_xlsx <- function(this_id){
    lst1 %>% map(~filter(., cyl == this_id)) %>% write_xlsx(paste0("ID_", this_id, ".xlsx"))
}

IDlist %>% map(make_one_xlsx)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yours created one file with 4 sheets, one for each ID. I would like to get 4 workbook, one for each ID. and it will contain 4 sheets, one for each data that are in lst, and sheetname is data name. (we might need to gave a name for the 4 mpg as mpg1, mpg2, mpg3, mpg4). Could you help me solve this puzzle. Many thanks.

Comment: Did you run the code? You get a different file for each ID in IDlist.  That's what `map` does.  I updated the answer to show how to name the excel sheets.  The names come from the list names.

Comment: My bad. It did created one for each ID. is it a way to name each sheet with data name. if the lst1 has 4 data.frame in it, with name `test1, result2,verify3,guess4`, how can I write in the data so the 4 work sheets in the workbook will be `test1, result2,verify3,guess4`

Comment: Did you try my updated answer?  If `lst1` is a named list, then those names become the sheet names.

Comment: Thanks a million. Yours should work. But when I run it , I got following error `[WARNING]: workbook_add_worksheet(): worksheet name 'Medical/Surgical History' has error: Worksheet name cannot contain invalid characters: '[ ] : * ? / \'
Error: Error in writexl: failed to create workbook
In addition: Warning message:
In write_xlsx(., paste0("ID_", Subject_id, ".xlsx")) :
  Truncating sheet name(s) to 31 characters` Is it a way to have the ouput without modify my data name? maybe  remove `/` automatically?

Comment: Okay.  I modified the answer to show how to automatically remove the bad characters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225422/discussion-between-stataq-and-michael-dewar).

Comment: Is it possible to save the output as a individual workbook and later write to excel with same name? If so, How? I tried many ways and could not get it. Your guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to add an additional sheet to an xlsx that already exists?  I don't know how to do that.  But I also recommend you don't do that.  Use a different workflow that avoids this.  In any case, I recommend that you open a new question with a clear questions if you still need help.

Answer (score 1):

you should show some example of your data for better answers.

you could use `xlsx` library

```
library('xlsx')


for(i in seq_along(lst1)){
    if(i == 1){
        append = FALSE
    } else{
        append = TRUE
    }
    write.xlsx(lst1[i], file='file_name.xlsx', 
               sheetName='get your id(sheet) name', append=append)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My case is different. I want to create a workbook for each ID, which has 10 sheets in each workbook  corresponding to each dataset in `lst1` So we need to loop from IDlist first, then write each data.frame with ID filter into each sheet. IF we have 5 ID, then we will have 5 workbook, 10 sheets in each one, 50 sheets in total.